# Opacity only on img not its background

Tags: image, css, opacity, background-color

I have this `img`:

```
<img src="img1.png" alt="" />
```

and this CSS:

```
img{
   background-color:green;
   opacity:0.4;
   padding:5px;
}
```

you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/majidgeek/GFJ2f/) that `img`'s `background-color` also faded. How can I give `opacity` only to `img` and **not** to its `background`?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be open for some more drastic changes. Canvas can do, adding a parent element can do or applying the filter on the image server side will do. Chances are that you actually can do exactly what you want with IE filters.

Comment: Opacity sets the transparency for the element img, which has the background-color applied. So it's transparent, too. You need another HTML element with the background-color behind the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GFJ2f/5/)

You need another surrounding HTML element to achieve this effect.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUOmz.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Setting `display` to `inline-block` wraps the `img`, without specifying any size.

Comment: I want that `img` faded to white

Comment: @majidgeek That's not what opacity means. Opacity will make you look through and you'll start seeing the color behind it. Put white behind if you want white.

Comment: @majidgeek What's the point with the green background-color then? What is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @KilianStinson You sould either make the img `vertical-align:bottom;` or `display:block;` to fix the 'white' space below the image. (at least in Chrome)

Comment: @RenéGeuze ok so how can I reach to my goal?

Comment: @RenéGeuze thanks, didn't noticed that. I prefer adding `font-size: 0`

Comment: @KilianStinson Font-size:0; gives issues on my mobile. Probably because there is a minimum font-size you can set on some browsers. But yeah, it usually works just fine as well :)